# Convert Flat json to Nested Json with multiple arrays and json should nested with flat json attribute

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm trying to write a spec to do the below transformation using jolt transformation. I need to convert the flat JSON to nested JSON.

Input Data is almost same as this question.

**Link:** [Convert Flat json to Nested Json with multiple arrays and keep null values in output using Jolt transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73582075/convert-flat-json-to-nested-json-with-multiple-arrays-and-keep-null-values-in-ou)

I am having some trouble with converting the flat JSON to nested JSON. Here, i want to aggregate the data based on **stoptype** attribute. I use https://jolt-demo.appspot.com to test the following below.

*Input Json:*

```
[
  {
    "container_id": "ABC",
    "shipperN": null,
    "PNumber": null,
    "trackingNumber": null,
    "priority": null,
    "loadNumber": "123345",
    "billOfLading": "12345",
    "addressLine1": "ABC Street",
    "addressLine2": null,
    "city": "Chicago",
    "country": "US",
    "latitude": null,
    "longitude": null,
    "earliestAppointmentTime": "XXXXX09:25",
    "latestAppointmentTime": "XXXXX09:25",
    "postalCode": "XXXXX3",
    "sequence": "1",
    "state": "XY",
    "stopReferenceId": "0001",
    "stopType": "PU",
    "containerNumber": "XXXXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "container_id": "ABC",
    "shipperN": null,
    "PNumber": null,
    "trackingNumber": null,
    "priority": null,
    "loadNumber": "123345",
    "billOfLading": "12345",
    "addressLine1": null,
    "addressLine2": null,
    "city": null,
    "country": null,
    "latitude": null,
    "longitude": null,
    "earliestAppointmentTime": "XXXXX09:25",
    "latestAppointmentTime": "XXXXX09:25",
    "name": null,
    "postalCode": null,
    "sequence": "2",
    "state": null,
    "stopReferenceId": "XXXXD",
    "stopType": "PL",
    "containerNumber": "XXXXXXXX"
  }
]
```

*Expected Output:*

```
[
  {
    "container_id": "ABC",
    "shipperN": null,
    "PNumber": null,
    "trackingNumber": null,
    "priority": null,
    "loadNumber": "123345",
    "billOfLading": "12345",
    "PU": 
      {
        "addressLine1": "ABC Street",
        "city": "Chicago",
        "country": "US",
        "earliestAppointmentTime": "XXXXX09:25",
        "latestAppointmentTime": "XXXXX09:25",
        "postalCode": "XXXXX3",
        "sequence": "1",
        "state": "XY",
        "stopReferenceId": "0001",
        "stopType": "PU"
      },
      "PL" : {
        "earliestAppointmentTime": "XXXXX09:25",
        "latestAppointmentTime": "XXXXX09:25",
        "sequence": "2",
        "stopReferenceId": "dummy",
        "stopType": "PL",
        "externalAddressId": "dummy"
     },
    "containerNumber": "XXXXXXXX"
 }
]
```

Here it is same jolt spec, i have used for last question.
**Link:** [Convert Flat json to Nested Json with multiple arrays and keep null values in output using Jolt transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73582075/convert-flat-json-to-nested-json-with-multiple-arrays-and-keep-null-values-in-ou)

Comment: As seen, you're trying to remove the attributes with `"null"` (*quoted*) values, but `"addressLine2" : "null"` is still kept within the desired result ...

Comment: Yes, I just edited that null values. can you check it. Here my main aim is to nested the flat json to a attribute of stop type. can you please share the code with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following explained specs

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&",
        "addressLine1": "@(1,stopType).&",
        "addressLine2": "@(1,stopType).&",
        "city": "@(1,stopType).&",
        "country": "@(1,stopType).&",
        "*AppointmentTime": "@(1,stopType).&",
        "sequence": "@(1,stopType).&",
        "state": "@(1,stopType).&",
        "stop*": "@(1,stopType).&",
        "post*": "@(1,stopType).&",
        "lat*|lon*|name": { // in order individually to get rid of the undesired null valued attributes
          "$": "@(0)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "PU|PL": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&2.&1.@(0)" // in order to get rid of all undesired null valued attributes nested within the subobjects PU and PL
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // revert key-value pairs in order to obtain the originals
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "container_id|shipperN|PNumber|trackingNumber|priority|loadNumber|billOfLading": "&", // indeed using "*":"&" is enough, but replaced after wish of sorting the containerNumber attribute at the bottom of the object 
      "PU|PL": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "&3.@(0)"
          }
        }
      },
      "containerNumber": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    // reduce only to a single one for the repeating components of the arrays
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": "ONE"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "[]"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much @Barbaros. I Understood the code. But How do i get the ""containerNumber": "XXXXXXXX"" at last attribute in json output. It comes in  middle of PU and PL

Comment: Just now, i have seen. Its working perfect. Thank you @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Özhan. Can you please look into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73662991/using-jolt-spec-how-can-i-convert-string-to-date-timestamp-format)

Comment: Hi @@Barbaros Özhan. In the jolt spec demo output. How do i get the output in List ("[]"). If you see the expected out and jolt demo output. Different is the output format, i need that output in list.

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Ozhan. Thanks for the response. I will return of the last question. Here in this question is, i want the output in Square brackets " [ ] ".

Comment: Can you please edit that code. How can i get the output in list. Ex: [ Output ]. Here, the above same output, i want to get it in list

Comment: Sure @Barbaros Ozhan . Definitely I will votup. Let me know once you fix this part

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Ozhan. I think its unable to handle the multiple inputs. Suppose if i'm adding two more dupicate records with change in "container_id": "DEF". Can you please check it. How can it aggregate based on container id if we give multiple inputs

Comment: Yes of course @VamsiKumar_gudala , since a cardinality spec with value `ONE` is used, based on the desired result in which the aim seems to be nest the attributes under common nodes. If you update one of the container_id values, an expected result should be presented along with it(the logic is completely changed ). This means asking a new question.

Comment: Is i need to ask this in new question @Barbaros Özhan ?

Comment: well, yes, the logic will be completely changed for returning attributes and how to nest them @VamsiKumar_gudala

Comment: Okay. i've posted, please lookin to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73702308/converting-flat-json-to-nested-json-for-multiple-payloads-using-jolt-transform)