# Using jolt transform, converting to nested json for multiple payloads

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Convert the flat json to nested json for the multiple payloads. I am having some trouble with converting the flat JSON to nested JSON. Here, i want to aggregate the data to stops and need to be aggregated for unique payloads. I use https://jolt-demo.appspot.com to test the following below.

**input:**

```
[
  {
    "container_id": "DEF_id",
    "haulType": "OL",
    "loadNumber": "DO123345",
    "billOfLading": "DO12345",
    "referenceNumbers": "LoadIDEF",
    "addressLine1": "DEF_address",
    "stopReferenceId": "0004",
    "stopType": "PL",
    "containerNumber": "454545"
  },
  {
    "container_id": "DEF_id",
    "haulType": "OL",
    "loadNumber": "DO123345",
    "billOfLading": "DO12345",
    "referenceNumbers": "LoadIDEF",
    "addressLine1": null,
    "stopReferenceId": "0003",
    "stopType": "PU",
    "containerNumber": "454545"
  },
  {
    "container_id": "ABC_id",
    "haulType": "IL",
    "loadNumber": "BO123345",
    "billOfLading": "BO12345",
    "referenceNumbers": "LoadID",
    "addressLine1": null,
    "stopReferenceId": "0002",
    "stopType": "PL",
    "containerNumber": "232323"
  },
  {
    "container_id": "ABC_id",
    "haulType": "IL",
    "loadNumber": "BO123345",
    "billOfLading": "BO12345",
    "referenceNumbers": "LoadID",
    "addressLine1": "ABC Street",
    "stopReferenceId": "0001",
    "stopType": "PU",
    "containerNumber": "232323"
  }
]
```

**Expected Output:**

```json
[
  {
    "load": {
      "container_id": "DEF_id",
      "haulType": [
        "OL"
      ],
      "loadNumber": "DO123345",
      "billOfLading": "DO12345",
      "referenceNumbers": [
        "LoadIDEF"
      ],
      "stops": [
        {
          "addressLine1": "DEF_address",
          "stopReferenceId": "0004",
          "stopType": "PL"
        },
        {
          "addressLine1": null,
          "stopReferenceId": "0003",
          "stopType": "PU"
        }
      ]
    },
    "containerInfo": {
      "containerNumber": "454545"
    }
  },
  {
    "load": {
      "container_id": "ABC_id",
      "haulType": [
        "IL"
      ],
      "loadNumber": "BO123345",
      "billOfLading": "BO12345",
      "referenceNumbers": [
        "LoadID"
      ],
      "stops": [
        {
          "addressLine1": null,
          "stopReferenceId": "0002",
          "stopType": "PL"
        },
        {
          "addressLine1": "ABC Street",
          "stopReferenceId": "0001",
          "stopType": "PU"
        }
      ]
    },
    "containerInfo": {
      "containerNumber": "232323"
    }
  }
]
```

**Here it is my jolt spec used**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "container_id": "@(1,containerNumber).load.&",
        "haulType": "@(1,containerNumber).load.&",
        "loadNumber": "@(1,containerNumber).load.&",
        "billOfLading": "@(1,containerNumber).load.&",
        "referenceNumbers": "@(1,containerNumber).load.&",
        "addressLine1": "@(1,containerNumber).load.stops[&1].&",
        "stopReferenceId": "@(1,containerNumber).load.stops[&1].&",
        "stopType": "@(1,containerNumber).load.stops[&1].&",
        "containerNumber": "@(1,containerNumber).containerInfo.&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "ONE",
          "stops": "MANY"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&",
        "load": {
          "haulType|referenceNumbers": "&1.&[]",
          "*": "&1.&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to individually write the attributes considering the expected result. You can partition by **`containerNumber`** values along with **`*`** and **`&`** wildcards to reperesent the key-value pairs of all attributes within the first spec. Then the separation of attributes(*conditional logic*) should be performed within the second spec in order to distinguish the display style of each key-value pairs such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@(1,containerNumber).&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "0": "&2.load.&1"
        },
        "haulType|referenceN*": {
          "0": "&2.load.&1[]" // 0 : pick only value of the first index from the array, &1[] : wrap up the values with square brackets
        },
        "addressLine1|stop*": {
          "*": "&2.load.stops[&].&1"
        },
        "containerN*": {
          "0": "&2.load.containerInfo.&1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of object labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site is http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ :

[image]